# Different images to appear on different pages (Wordpress / PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress / PHP. Please can you advise the best way I can display images within a page through Wordpress? They don't have to be edited in the admin but can be if it is easier to do so.

Currently I am doing it like this;

```
<?php if (is_page(43)) { ?>
<img src="/images/notting-hill-4.jpg">
<img src="/images/notting-hill-5.jpg">

<?php } elseif (is_page(162)) {  ?>

<img src="/images/notting-hill-7.jpg">
<img src="/images/notting-hill-8.jpg">
<img src="/images/notting-hill-9.jpg">


<?php } else { ?>

<img src="/images/notting-hill-1.jpg">
<img src="/images/notting-hill-2.jpg">
<img src="/images/notting-hill-3.jpg">

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why dont you add them in the admin section?

Comment: You can upload and place images directly into your pages through the Wordpress interface.  Although, if you want to change which images are shown (say in a header, or something) based on which page you are viewing, you could look into setting up different page templates. http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Answer (score 0):

You could for example use the NextGen gallery plugin. Find it here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Create a gallery for each page. Then use shortcodes or the other ways provided to display your images as you want them. Don't be fooled by the gallery features, it will also allow you to display the individual images (I am very certain of, although it was a while since I used this.)

Answer (score 0):

You could  to use different templates and set the templates in the editor and then each page has different type of template

Read more at:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_into_Templates

If the pages have the same template you would probably just need to add images directly into the post or page editor